# intent on incoming hangouts dialer number is null

Tags: android

Incoming number on moto G 4G kitkat from outgoing hangouts dialer call on another device...

Stock phone app **and/or**

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    number = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Both produce: NULL

Incoming number from other outgoing source is not null and is shown.

**However**

```
Log.d(TAG, "isEmpty? " +extras.isEmpty());
```

Produces: InPhoneStateMonitor(4661): isEmpty? false

Though perhaps its the state information or other:

```
String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
```

There is also nothing I can see in hangouts to make a difference. Haven't checked google voice account settings from the website or tried from my old Google voice number through hangouts either.

**In the end my question is**: Why is there no phone number being received or at least appears to be null from that source?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it appears I just figured out how to get a non-null number as my old Google voice number is not null from hangout dialer outgoing call...

The account I use on my devices never had a Google voice number registered and at the Google voice website settings -> phones tab shows:
 Your Google voicemail access number (xxx)xxx-xxxx
 Get a Google Voice number

So guessing it is that, or in other words, a provider configuration issue as the number should not be null regardless.